# Cannot resolve the name X to an element declaration component in a recursive xml schema

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I'm just beginning working with XML schemas. I'm creating a simple schema and I don't understand why I get an error while trying to implement a simple recursive element. I'm sure it's totally trivial.

Here I get the following error: *E [Xerces] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'node' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="node">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element ref="node" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And here, not having the `root` element, I don't get the error...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="node">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="node" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I am totally mesmerized 0_0. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to *refer* to an element, it must be declared as top level. You can have both `root` and `node` referring to the same element using:

```
<xs:element ref="node" />
```

That's why your second example works. You can use this schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="node">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="node" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="root">
       <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element ref="node" />
           </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks now I understand better! I found out the how myself but not the why ;)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have solved my issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xs:element name="root">
       <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element name="node_" type="nodeType"/>
           </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="nodeType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="node" type="nodeType"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```